# Accessing a file within Java project

Tags: java, eclipse, file-io

I have a Java project which uses a third party application. I have the license file (.lic format) stored in the resources folder. Upon running the Ant script, it will copy this file into the /lib/jar directory as it rolls up the project into a Jar file to use on the server. This is where I will need to access the file when running the system live. Here is how the folder structure looks

```
MyProject
  src
    package
      AccessingClass.java
  resources
    File.lic
  lib
    jar
      File.lic (upon copy from Ant)
```

I am not sure the best way to do this so any suggestions other than how I have been trying will probably be helpful. The 3rd party project has a method in a class like License.setLicense(), which can either take a String to the location or an InputStream of the file.

I have been playing around with feeding it an InputStream, but always get a null value when calling getClass().getResourceAsStream().  Here is everything I have tried:

- getClass().getResourceAsStream("../../../lib/jar/File.lic");
         getClass().getResourceAsStream("/File.lic");

And as a backup I also tried (for local builds I figure I would try the resource folder):

- getClass().getResourceAsStream("../../../resources/File.lic");
         getClass().getResourceAsStream("/File.lic");

Is there a better method to perform this action? Or would someone be able to tell me why what I am trying is failing? Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Where inside the JAR (e.g. if you unpack it, is the file located? lib/jar? resources? at the root?

Answer (score 0):

**First, you need to ensure that the `JAR` is added in your class path**.

Below should work.

```
  InputStream inputStream = 
    getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/resources/File.lic");
```

Assuming `File.lic` is placed in root folder of the jar.

Comment: It is not in the root of the Jar folder however, it is where I specified above. I can access this via a direct path, I am just not sure what that would look like.

Comment: @ozpenstillson: Is it in `resources` folder? You jar structore wasn't having mention of the same. You can use the path starting from root in the file name. I updated the answer with the details.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this code standalone or in IDE env looks like classpath issue. If you are running at command prompt you have to set classpath to lib dir if in ide make sure you resources dir is in classpath.

Comment: I added both the lib and the resources folder to the classpath on our local tomcat server (to test first) and on the project build path. Still receiving null.